# Ext jS 4: Store-Model combo; dynamically configuring fields

Tags: extjs, extjs4

im trying to make a dynamicly configurated model-store work.

If i only use a store it WILL work;

```
    var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: modelTableStructure['fieldsModel'],
        proxy: {
            type:'ajax',
            url: Ext.ux.db.vars.urlGetTableData,
            actionMethods: {
                read: 'POST'
            },
            extraParams:{
                servidorSql: serverConfig.servidorSql,
                dbLogin: serverConfig.dbLogin,
                dbPass: serverConfig.dbPass,
                db:db,
                tabla:tabla
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

But if I introduce a model it WONT work;

```
    var gridModel = Ext.create('Ext.data.Model',{
        fields: modelTableStructure['fieldsModel']
    });

    var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: gridModel,
        proxy: {
            type:'ajax',
            url: Ext.ux.db.vars.urlGetTableData,
            actionMethods: {
                read: 'POST'
            },
            extraParams:{
                servidorSql: serverConfig.servidorSql,
                dbLogin: serverConfig.dbLogin,
                dbPass: serverConfig.dbPass,
                db:db,
                tabla:tabla
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

Firebug's error; Fields is undefined. I have tried to separate the store and model in separate files (typical Ext JS 4 MVC) using constructors and tracking that every variable is correct; same error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `Ext.define` for Model definitions, because the store will do the `Ext.create`ing of your model when new "records" are added to the store. The model is already assumed to have defined fields when you do `Ext.create('myGridModel',{})`.

For instance,

```
    Ext.define('myGridModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: modelTableStructure['fieldsModel']
    });

    var gridStore = Ext.create(Ext.data.Store, {
        model: 'myGridModel',
        // other config options below
    });
```

See [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) for more details.